# Is there any significance to the rhyme "Ten lay sleeping in the West"?

Tags: elric-saga

In the last pages of *Dragon Lords of Melnibone*, a 3rd edition D&D supplement based on Michael Moorcock's *Elric Saga*, there is a section titled Rumors, which describes much of the magic of the Elric universe, including other planes, various magic artifacts (including the swords Stormbringer and Mournblade) and characters/monsters.

One entry in this section is the following children's rhyme:

"Ten lay sleeping in the West,
Black hands folded chest on chest,
Please, please grant them longer rest"

Does this rhyme refer to anyone in particular in the saga, or is it just atmosphere/flavor text?

Comment: "Ten" plus "black hands" makes me think of the [Nihrain](https://stormbringer.fandom.com/wiki/Nihrain), but I don't know if their city is in the west.

Answer (score 20):

The "Ten who sleep" appear in the 1965 book Stormbringer:

> Sepiriz smiled slightly. "You know us. I think-or at least you know of us. There was a certain friendship between your ancestors and our folk in the early years of the Bright Empire." He paused a moment before continuing: "Have you ever heard legends, in Imrryr perhaps, of the Ten from the mountain? The ten who sleep in the mountain of fire?"
>
> "Many times." Elric drew in his breath. "Now I recognise you by description. But it is said that you sleep for centuries in the mountain of fire. Why are you roaming abroad in this manner?"
>
> "We were driven by an eruption from our volcano home which had been dormant for two thousand years. Such movements of nature have been taking place all over the earth of late. Our time, we knew, had come to awaken again. We were servants of Fate-and our mission is strongly bound up with your destiny. We bear a message for you from Zarozinia's captor-and another from a different source. Would you return now, with us, to the Chasm of Nihrain and learn all we can tell you?"

They are indeed black. In the book Sepiriz is described as a "black giant".

The role of the ten is to ensure that Elric follows his fate to bring about the end of the world and the start of a new age, which presumably is why the author of the rhyme was not eager to see them awakened.

Comment: The chapter introducing them begins, "Ten terrible men...."